# What's behind the word "size issues"?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, intuition, paradoxes

I occasionally hear the term "size issues", which refers to situations where a certain collection of objects "is too big to be a set". What does one mean by "too big to be a set"? Why is bigness contradictory (it's only contradictory if one assumes the axiom of replacement, right)? Is "bigness" a clear defined term? It doesn't seem so:

In the book *Set theory: an introduction* by Vaught, it says on page 12:

> But the idea 'big' remains vague and our remarks about 'bigness' are to be taken only heuristic.

But using replacement and global choice, one can prove the following rigorous theorem:

A class is a proper class if and only if it's bijective to V, the class of all sets.

Isn't this theorem saying that "too big" really has a precise meaning?

When one talks about "bigness", does one assume the axiom of replacement? I think so, because otherwise the term wouldn't make so much sense in combination with contradictions.

Comment: To paraphrase Douglas Adams, "The universal set is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, **if** you have global choice, then you can prove the principle you speak about, which is known as [Limitation of Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size).

However, in most cases where the informal "too big to be a set" argument is used, one is generally assumed to be working in ZF(C), where neither global choice nor limitation of size can even be stated. Generally, what this informal argument means is something like

> If the collection of all the things you're speaking about there constituted a set, then it follows that there would also need to be a set of all sets (or a set of all ordinals), in which case Russell's paradox (or Burali-Forti's) would obtain a contradiction. So your collection definitely *does not* specify a set.

Here, the step where you conclude "there would need to be a set of all sets" *often* involves Replacement, but not necessarily. For example, the collection of all singletons is "too big" just by virtue of the Axiom of Union -- and similarly, taking the union a small finite number of times will be enough to show that collections like "all groups" or "all small categories" are too big to be sets.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that initially "too big" is just a vague idea, like "a set shouldn't be so large, that we can construct the set of all sets (or the set of all sets that don't conatin themselves as elements) from it; because that would lead to a contradiction". And after a while, if one adds proper classes to the picture, assumes global choice and replacement, then one can revisit this vague idea about "bigness" and formulate limitation of size as a precise theorem, which can be rigorously proved with our axioms? Is this your point?

Comment: @Nullachtfünfzehn: More or less, yes. My foremost objection to your description is that it sounds like you think "vague idea" is a _shortcoming_ of the idea and that one _should_ want replace it with your precise theorem. In the majority of cases, the "vague" idea is all one ever wants or needs. The limitation-of-size axiom makes things _look_ somewhat tidier, but it is not really clear that what it tells us is practically _useful_, so changing which set theory we work in just for that minor bit of tidiness won't be on most people's agenda.

Comment: As a minor point: the axiom of replacement is not usually considered something you explicitly decide to assume; it's simply part of the standard set theoretic background of ZF (or NBG). It is _historically_ true that it came later than the other axioms (and is responsible for the F in ZFC), but few people are interested in working in Z other than out of historical interest, or as a didactic stepping-stone towards ZFC.

Comment: Thanks for the additional remarks. Is it from a naive point of view conceivable that also "small" sets can lead to contradictions?

Comment: @Nullachtfünfzehn: No; if you can prove that your definable collection definably _injects into_ something that is known to be a set, then the collection must itself be a set, courtesy of the axiom of replacement.

Comment: I mean if one doesn't have replacement, is it then conceivable?

Comment: @Nullachtfünfzehn: Lacking an axiom (such as replacement) will never _lead to_ contradictions -- if a contradiction can be derived from the smaller set of axioms then it can be derived from the full set of axioms too. Without replacement I suppose it is possible that one can have a collection that injects into a set but is not itself a set -- but "is not a set" does not imply that being a set would create a contradiction; it might just be how things happen to be in the model we're looking at.

Answer (score 7):

The point is that Replacement guarantees that a class which can be put in bijection with a set, is a set. Here class means a definable collection, and a bijection means definable bijection.

If every set has a cardinality, then proper classes are "too big" to have a cardinality. Which is exactly the idea.

The thing is, that assuming global choice, every two proper classes are equipotent. So there is just "one size" of proper classes.

Without Replacement it is possible that there is a proper class which is countable, in the sense that there is a definable bijection between the natural numbers and the class. And if that is not a motivation to accept Replacement, I don't know what is...

Comment: To provide a simple example for your last point: Consider $V_{\omega + \omega}$. Here Replacement fails, every other axiom of ZFC holds and $\{ \omega + n \mid n < \omega \}$ is a proper class in $V_{\omega + \omega}$ for which $V_{\omega + \omega}$ has a definable bijection with $\omega$.

Comment: Yes, that is the go to example. However, the OP wrote in a previous question that they don't know yet what is the von Neumann hierarchy, which is why I didn't give this example.

Answer (score 0):

For small sets the property that a given object is in the set is very restrictive. For example, the property a given 'thing' is a a number between $7$ and $456$ is very discerning in a universal sense. However, the property that a set doesn't contain itself doesn't rule out too many objects, so in a loose sense, it allows enough elements that it's membership property is no longer consistent with our intuitive or axiomatic notions of membership.

The 'set' or class described in the latter example is the subject of russel's paradox, an inconsistency implied by the axiom of comprehension, the defunct axiom that any well formed property defines a set. So a distinction had to made between sets and classes, and sets are defined in a hierarchy from other sets so that "barber who only shaves..." classes won't become actual sets in your theory. The result is that some collections like 'the set of real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$' are sets and collections like 'the set of all sets' and 'the set of all real valued maps on any $X$' are not.

Answer (score 0):

I think people (who live alongside infinities) are reluctant to say that the idea of something being big is a real mathematical statement because it is known to be relative.

When presented as you did, it seems that "being too big" really means being as big as it is possible. But look at a countable model of ZFC. Its universe is externally as big as any infinite set in it (some of which might internally be regarded as finite), so then being too big is just allowing a correspondance with the universe: this needs not be an intrinsic property of the class or of the set of elements (according to the model) of this class, but this depends on the whole model.

When you look closer at why some things are "too big", you find out that the limitations are more subtle that you could think. One instance of this is the limitation that appears when a notion has a wide range that allows self reference in some way, and that a contrary to this notion exists. Famous and direct instances of this are:

-$V$ is "too big" to be a set because of the notion "element of $\ . \ $"
-$\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{N})$ is "bigger" than $\mathbb{N}$ because the notion "element of $f(.)$" 
-$Ord$ is too big to be a set for arguably the same reason.

Limitation of size synthesizes this but it is debatable whether the idea of size is really the key point in those matters.

Despite that, the image of size works because it is in accordance with the naïve (yet true by comprehension) idea that subclasses are tinier: a sublass of a set is a set.

I hope this is not too vague.

Comment: Note that "a subclass of a set is a set" is *not* true in all set theories, e.g. NF.